# Constructing a priority queue of vectors

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I am looking for a simple STL implementation of a priority queue of vectors. Each vector has exactly 4 elements. I want to sort my priority queue on the basis of the 3rd element of each vector. The vector with the lowest 3rd element should come at the top(min priority queue of vectors).

How to implement this in C++?

Also, if anybody has the actually STL implementation of default priority queue, please provide a link. Like the official implementation inside the STL.

Comment: Use `std::array`, it would me more efficient for fixed size.

Comment: @RHertel Isn't better to use standard array container and provide custom comparator to `std::priority_queue`?

Comment: @DanielLangr Yes, I know but other implementations of my code require vector properties. But still, thank you.

Comment: @RHertel Do you have a link to read about this? Any kind of material would be helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to create your own *comparator* to compare elements of the `priority_queue`.

Something like this:

```
// How to compare elements
struct my_comparator
{
    // queue elements are vectors so we need to compare those
    bool operator()(std::vector<int> const& a, std::vector<int> const& b) const
    {
        // sanity checks
        assert(a.size() == 4);
        assert(b.size() == 4);

        // reverse sort puts the lowest value at the top    
        return a[2] > b[2];
    }
};

// for usability wrap this up in a type alias:
using my_priority_queue = std::priority_queue<std::vector<int>, std::vector<std::vector<int>>, my_comparator>;

int main()
{
    my_priority_queue mpq;

    mpq.push({1, 2, 1, 4});
    mpq.push({1, 2, 2, 4});
    mpq.push({1, 2, 3, 4});

    // etc ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please consider using STL data-structure `priority_queue`. I faced similar problem before and this code should help.

I think before posting answers we need to check if our answer builds correctly. So this is working program but you should not use `using namespace std;`, please change it with `std::`:

```
#include <functional>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T> void print_queue(T& q) {
    while(!q.empty()) {
        vector<int> tmp;
        tmp = q.top();
        std::cout << tmp[2] << " ";
        q.pop();
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

struct Compare {
    bool operator()(vector<int> const & a, vector<int> const & b)
    { return a[2] > b[2]; }
};

int main()
{

    vector<int> v1;
    vector<int> v2;
    vector<int> v3;
    vector<int> v4;

    priority_queue< vector<int>, vector< vector<int> >, Compare > pr_q;

    int a[5] = { 1,2,3,4 };
    v1.insert(v1.end(), a, a+4); v1[2] = 11; // v1 = {1, 2, 11, 4}
    v2.insert(v2.end(), a, a+4); v2[2] = -1; // v1 = {1, 2, -1, 4}
    v3.insert(v3.end(), a, a+4); v3[2] = 22; // v1 = {1, 2, 22, 4}
    v4.insert(v4.end(), a, a+4); v4[2] = 31; // v1 = {1, 2, 31, 4}

    pr_q.push(v1);
    pr_q.push(v2);
    pr_q.push(v3);
    pr_q.push(v4);

    print_queue(pr_q);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know that some improvements and corrections could be applied but I think it answers the question. So, cheers!

Comment: The comparator sign should be 'greater than' because by default priority queue are implemented using max-heap and not min-heaps. I think you should change the compare sign.

Answer (score 0):

Galiks example is good. I would however not put the sanity check in the comparator if following the principle of one function - one task. More details on http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue. Using lambda we can implement it as follows:

```
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

int main(){
    auto cmp = [](std::vector<int> left, std::vector<int> right) { return(left[2]) > (right[2]);};

    std::priority_queue<std::vector<std::vector<int>>, std::vector<std::vector<int>>, decltype(cmp)> q(cmp);

    q.push({1,2,1,3});
    q.push({1,2,2,3});
    q.push({1,2,3,3});
    q.push({1,2,4,3});

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `std::priority_queue` with a custom comparator.

```
using QueueElement = std::vector<int>;

auto compare_third_element = [](const QueueElement& lhs, const QueueElement& rhs) 
                             { 
                                assert(lhs.size() > 2 && rhs.size() > 2);
                                return lhs[2] > rhs[2]; 
                             };

using MyPriorityQueue = std::priority_queue < QueueElement, std::vector<QueueElement>, decltype(compare_third_element)>;
MyPriorityQueue my_queue(compare_third_element);

my_queue.emplace(QueueElement{ 0,0,2 });
my_queue.emplace(QueueElement{ 0,0,3 });
my_queue.emplace(QueueElement{ 0,0,1 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>

using namespace std; 

priority_queue<vector<int>> pq; 

void max(vector<int> v) 
{ 
    for(int i=0; i<v.size();i++) 
    { 
        cout<<v[i]<<" "; 
    } 
    cout<<endl; 
    return; 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    vector<int> inp1{10,20,30,40}; 
    vector<int> inp2{10,20,35,40}; 
    vector<int> inp3{30,25,10,50};
    vector<int> inp4{20,10,30,40};
    vector<int> inp5{5,10,30,40};

    pq.push(inp1); 
    pq.push(inp2); 
    pq.push(inp3); 
    pq.push(inp4); 
    pq.push(inp5); 
    max(pq.top()); 
}
```

Comment: Print the maximum vector that is in a queue
Define priority queue like this
priority_queue<vector<int> > "Queuename";

Answer (score -1):

#include 
#include

using namespace std;

```
void max(vector<int> v) 
{ 
for(int i=0; i<v.size();i++) 
{ 
    cout<<v[i]<<" "; 
} 
cout<<endl; 
};

struct my_comparator
{
    bool operator()(vector<int> const& a,vector<int> const& b) const
    {
        return a>b;
    }
};

priority_queue<vector<int>, vector<vector<int>>, my_comparator>pq;

int main() 
{
    vector<int> inp1{10,20,30,40}; 
    vector<int> inp2{10,20,35,40}; 
    vector<int> inp3{30,25,10,50};
    vector<int> inp4{20,10,30,40};
    vector<int> inp5{5,10,30,40};

    pq.push(inp1); 
    pq.push(inp2); 
    pq.push(inp3); 
    pq.push(inp4); 
    pq.push(inp5); 

    max(pq.top()); 
}
```